# Rank-2 polymorphism with a type variable constrained by another type variable

Tags: haskell

Suppose we want to write a function `ifE` that takes a boolean, two handler functions (producing results of different types but implementing the same type class `c`), and some postprocessing function that can handle arbitrary `c`'s. In other words, we want to generalize this function over `Show`:

```hs
ifShow :: (Show b1, Show b2)
       => Bool
       -> (a -> b1)
       -> (a -> b2)
       -> a
       -> (forall v. Show v => v -> res)
       -> res
ifShow b f1 f2 arg postproc = if b then postproc (f1 arg) else postproc (f2 arg)
```

I've heard there's `ConstraintKinds`, so let's turn that on and write this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Kind

ifE :: forall (c :: Type -> Constraint) a b1 b2 res
     . (c b1, c b2)
    => Bool
    -> (a -> b1)
    -> (a -> b2)
    -> a
    -> (forall v. c v => v -> res)
    -> res
ifE b f1 f2 arg postproc = if b then postproc (f1 arg) else postproc (f2 arg)
```

Now, GHC (8.10.4 in my case) complains about the type signature itself:

```
Main.hs:5:8: error:
    • Could not deduce: (c0 b1, c0 b2)
      from the context: (c b1, c b2)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   ifE :: forall (c :: * -> Constraint) a b1 b2 res.
                          (c b1, c b2) =>
                          Bool
                          -> (a -> b1)
                          -> (a -> b2)
                          -> a
                          -> (forall v. c v => v -> res)
                          -> res
        at Main.hs:(5,8)-(12,10)
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘ifE’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        ifE :: forall (c :: Type -> Constraint) a b1 b2 res.
               (c b1, c b2) =>
               Bool
               -> (a -> b1)
                  -> (a -> b2) -> a -> (forall v. c v => v -> res) -> res
  |
5 | ifE :: forall (c :: Type -> Constraint) a b1 b2 res
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

Main.hs:5:8: error:
    • Could not deduce: c v
      from the context: (c b1, c b2)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   ifE :: forall (c :: * -> Constraint) a b1 b2 res.
                          (c b1, c b2) =>
                          Bool
                          -> (a -> b1)
                          -> (a -> b2)
                          -> a
                          -> (forall v. c v => v -> res)
                          -> res
        at Main.hs:(5,8)-(12,10)
      or from: c0 v
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   forall v. c0 v => v -> res
        at Main.hs:(5,8)-(12,10)
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘ifE’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        ifE :: forall (c :: Type -> Constraint) a b1 b2 res.
               (c b1, c b2) =>
               Bool
               -> (a -> b1)
                  -> (a -> b2) -> a -> (forall v. c v => v -> res) -> res
  |
5 | ifE :: forall (c :: Type -> Constraint) a b1 b2 res
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

I understand that GHC *might* have trouble figuring out what `c` should be (although I'm not sure why it *would* — can't it do that by unifying `c` with the type of `postproc` at the call site?), but the error is telling something slightly different. Namely, for some reason another type variable `c0` is introduced, although I would expect `c` to be bound by the outer `forall`. What's going on, and where did I mess up?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: I think there's no good reason to pass an `a -> b1` and an `a -> b2` and an `a`. Just pass the `b1` and the `b2` that you get from applying these functions. (Remember laziness.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks fine, you can turn on `AllowAmbiguousTypes` as suggested. By default, GHC rejects the type because when `ifE` is called, `c` can not be deduced from the type of arguments.

To better understand why `c` is ambiguous, note that this type checks:

```
> foo :: (forall t. Ord t => t->t->Bool) -> Bool ; foo f = f True True
> bar :: forall t. Eq t => t->t->Bool ; bar x y = x == y
> foo bar
True
```

Note how `Eq` and `Ord` do not have to match, it suffices that `Ord` is a subclass of `Eq`.

Hence, in your code `c` does not have to be matched exactly, but represents any subclass of the actual constraint found in your `postproc`.

Because of this, you will likely also need `TypeApplications` later on to disambiguate calls to your `ifE`.